# Fixed issue with connecting to docker but don't know why the fix worked

Tags: docker

I had trouble connecting to my `hbase docker` via `hbase shell` from my local machine so I went into the container and did `netstat -atp tcp | grep -i "listen"`

```
tcp        0      0 03de42531368:16000      :::*                    LISTEN      184/java
tcp        0      0 :::9090                 :::*                    LISTEN      507/java
tcp        0      0 :::2181                 :::*                    LISTEN      12/java
tcp        0      0 :::9095                 :::*                    LISTEN      507/java
tcp        0      0 03de42531368:16201      :::*                    LISTEN      276/java
tcp        0      0 :::16010                :::*                    LISTEN      184/java
tcp        0      0 :::16301                :::*                    LISTEN      276/java
tcp        0      0 :::http-alt             :::*                    LISTEN      373/java
tcp        0      0 :::8085                 :::*                    LISTEN      373/java
```

I saw my container in the response. Then I updated `/etc/hosts` with `03de42531368` pointing to `127.0.0.1`. Afterwards, I was able to connect to my hbase docker.

That fixed the issue, however I had no idea why I saw my container id in the netstat response and had to add `03de42531368` to `/etc/hosts`.

Can anyone explain?

Comment: To be clear you are saying that it did not previously work when you were accessing `127.0.0.1:16201` or `127.0.0.1:16000` without the hosts entry? If so may be useful to have some info about what is running in the container as it may be doing something funny with requests which don't use the "correct" hostname.

Comment: @sprkysnrky I'm not sure which one since I'm using `hbase shell` to connect to `hbase`. I'm using the [harisekhon/hbase-dev/](https://hub.docker.com/r/harisekhon/hbase-dev/) docker image.